# file upload status information

Tags: python, upload, curl

Im making a small python script to upload files on the net. The script is working correctly, and now I want to add a simple progress bar that indicates the amount of uploading left. my question is -how do I get the upload status  information from the server where im uploading the file, assuming it is possible...I am using curl and pycurl to make the http requests in python. 
Any help will be much appreciated, Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation here: http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/callbacks.html for callbacks. Best of luck!